# Embeddable database with hooks for custom code on insert/delete/update

Tags: database, c++, notification, embeddable

I am looking for one embedded database written `C++` with ability subscribing to events like *value changed*, *value deleted*, *value added in values class*, etc.
**Platforms:** posix, so almost any.
At this moment I am looking on `SQLite` and `leveldb`.
May be you know how to add this ability? Or may be another cool database?

Comment: Surely the database does not __have__ to be written in `C++` as long as it has a C++ API. Do you have any price/licence constraints?

Comment: Yes. OpenSource is in preference.co

Comment: Just to make sure I understant what you're requesting: You want the DB to expose hooks for functions to get called for each record as it's about to be deleted/updated or right after it's been added?

Comment: @einpoklum absolutely yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Steve said, you don’t really need a database that was coded in C++, unless you plan to extend its functionality. All you care about is a database that interfaces well with C++.

For that, you need a database connector  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_connection  and (almost?) all popular databases will offer one.

Have you decided whether you want/need a relational database  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database  or a “NoSQL database”? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL

After that decision, just look at popular free DBs  http://blog.capterra.com/free-database-software/ and choose one which is right for you (we can’t help you with that, sorry).

[Sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/), which you mentioned is fine, and has the advantage that you can link it with your code and so release only a single executable, with no additional files, and has good documentation and support, but ultimately the choice is yours.

---

[Update] in response to OP’s comment.

I personally recommend having a single running instance of a single  application which is the only database user. I do this in case I have multiple remote clients. My app can handle contention when multiple clients want to read/write simultaneously. Of course, the database can take care of that, but I prefer to know about it & have control of it. If you implement that way, you don’t need to know about database triggers, because your database control app can generate them.

If you don’t have a  single debase control app, and have lots of distributed copies of your client app, then triggers is how they will know when the database has been updated.

If that’s all that you want, then you can go with Sqlite or MySql if you have a database control app. If you have multiple client apps, go with Mysql.

Comment: My main point is **event-driven embedded** database. Other is secondary

Comment: I have updated my answer to add more info.

Comment: Nice update. Anyway I need to write some wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

I think you *might* be able to get [MonetDB](https://www.monetdb.org/) to do that. Or rather, I'm sure you can do it in a not-fun way by writing a custom MAL module which wraps your C++ code - which you would add to a clone of the MonetDB codebase, since MonetDB is FOSS; then you could submit queries in MAL (the operation interpreter into which MonetDB parses SQL queries) which use your code. If it were Python or R functions it would have been much simpler and easier.

H-o-w-e-v-e-r - MonetDB is a column store, not a row store; and it's more analytics-oriented than transaction oriented, so I'm not sure that would be such a great solution performance-wise. If you're still interested, you should probably re-ask your question with more specific details on what you intend to do, on the [MonetDB user mailing list](http://mailto:users-list@monetdb.org).

Now, if you want to go the embdedded way with MonetDB, well, it *is* embeddable - there's an R embedding of it named [MonetDBLite](https://www.monetdb.org/blog/monetdblite-r). I'm not sure how much work it would be to adapt an embedding to work with a C++ application: It could be a lot, since MonetDB is a big project with some cruft here and there; but it could be not so much, considering how it's a *C language* project. If you want to discuss this option, talk to [Dr. Hannes Mulheisen](http://mailto:hannes.muehleisen@cwi.nl)  at my group at CWI.